# Simplify PHP multiply if conditions

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I wonder is there any way to make this code more subtle?

Ex

```
 public function hookDisplayHeader()
{
    if(Tools::getValue('controller')=='index'){
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'something.css', 'all');
    }
    if(Tools::getValue('controller')=='cms'){
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'something.css', 'all');
    }
    if(Tools::getValue('controller')=='product'){
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'something.css', 'all');
    }
    if(Tools::getValue('controller')=='category'){
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'something.css', 'all');
    }

}
```

to simple

```
 public function hookDisplayHeader()
     {
         if(Tools::getValue('controller')=='index AND product AND cms AND category'){
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'something.css', 'all');
         }
     }
```

this code not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in_array();`

```
public function hookDisplayHeader()
{
    $values = array('index','cms','product','category');
    if(in_array(Tools::getValue('controller'), $values)){
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'something.css', 'all');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would place them in an array and check that:

```
$somethingCSSControllers = array('index','product','cms','category');

if(in_array(Tools::getValue('controller'),$somethingCSSControllers)){
    $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'something.css', 'all');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim! Works too but Tom gives me answer that is better to understand for me :)